# Enable Site Feature Guids

Tags: sharepoint-online, feature, guid

In the past I've used a feature in a sharepoint implementation that would generate a GUID for every file uploaded.  If I recall it correctly I found this feature in Site Settings> Site Features.  However I am having trouble finding this exact feature in a new implementation. I've tried looking through the enabled features of the previus sharepoint site where I enabled this feature but I can't recognise any of the features as the one I am talking about.

An example of a generated GUID from the old implementation: [image: generated guid]

When i say old implementation and new implementation I am talking about 2 modern sharepoint environments in sharepoint online. Completely different Tenants.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the Document ID service feature.

It is found at the site collection level.

So, you need to go to the site collection settings > site collection features (under site collection administration header) and enable the Document ID service feature. You need to be a site collection admin to be able to activate it.

Reference - [Track documents in SP using document ID feature](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-track-documents-in-sharepoint-using-document-id-feature/)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Site Collection Settings -> Site Collection Features under Site Collection Administration -> Activate the Document ID Service feature.

After activating the Document ID Service feature, modify the library view, tick the box next to "Document ID" column.

References:

[Activate and configure Document IDs in a site collection](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/activate-and-configure-document-ids-in-a-site-collection-66345c77-f079-4104-ac7a-e25826849306)

[Using Document IDs with SharePoint Online](https://www.petri.com/using-document-ids-sharepoint-online)

[SharePoint Online and Document ID](https://joannecklein.com/2018/11/16/sharepoint-online-and-document-id-the-goods/)